# Email input instant validation with javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, email, input, onblur

I'm trying to validate input `type="email"` with `js`.

I found different ways to do that but non of them works form me.

**HTML**

```
<label for="email" class="form__label">User e-mail:</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" onblur="checkEmail(this.value);" class="form__input" >
```

**JS**

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var email = document.getElementById('email');

  function checkEmail(email) {
    var reg1 = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;

    if (reg1.test(email) == false) {
      email.style.border = "1px solid red";
    }else (reg1.test(email) == true) {
      email.style.border = "1px solid green";
    }
  };

});
```

What I get every time is:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: checkEmail is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onblur .`..

I know, I make some simple error but I'm struggling with this for a while now and can't move on...

Comment: Can I ask why you trying to achieve that? Isn't the HTML5 default check good?

Comment: You can simply add 'required' to your email input.

Comment: I have to change the border color so I guess 'required' is not enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could ineed use the Email Check of HTML5 as quoted by @Andriy Klitsuk. So you could completely omit your extra `checkEmail` call.

But getting to your error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: checkEmail is not defined at
>   HTMLInputElement.onblur

you get the above error as the `checkEmail` function is present inside EventHandler `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ ....` and hence is not available outside it.

You could take the function out of the EventListener as it is not being called inside the EventHandler anyway :

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var email = document.getElementById('email');
  });
  function checkEmail(email) {
    var reg1 = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;

    if (reg1.test(email) == false) {
      email.style.border = "1px solid red";
    } else if (reg1.test(email) == true) { // if was missing here
      email.style.border = "1px solid green";
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing **If** keyword in your code i.e

```
else (reg1.test(email) == true)
```

```js
 

  var email = document.getElementById('email');

  function checkEmail(element) {
    var reg1 = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/; 
    if (reg1.test(email.value) == false) {
    email.style.border ='1px solid red';
    }else if(reg1.test(email.value) == true){
      email.style.border = "1px solid green";
    }
  };
```

```html
<label for="email" class="form__label">User e-mail:</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" onblur="checkEmail(this);" class="form__input" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer passing the element

```
<label for="email" class="form__label">User e-mail:</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" onblur="checkEmail(this);" class="form__input" >
```

And the function would get the value as follows

```
function checkEmail(email) {
    var val = email.value;
    var reg1 = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;

    if (reg1.test(email) == false) {
      email.style.border = "1px solid red";
    }else if (reg1.test(email) == true) {
      email.style.border = "1px solid green";
    }
  };
```

also an if is missing

code pen for reference
https://codepen.io/YasirKamdar/pen/eVRaYZ?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the condition as well. simply use this.

```
  function checkEmail(elm) {
    var reg1 = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
console.log(reg1.test(elm.value))
    if (reg1.test(elm.value) == false){
      elm.style.border = "1px solid red";
    }else{
     elm.style.border = "1px solid green";
    }
  }

<label for="email" class="form__label">User e-mail:</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" onblur="checkEmail(this);" class="form__input" >
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, there is a syntax error in your `else` statement. It should be `else if`. Now to the solution; remove the `checkEmail()` function from the `eventListener` and let it stand alone, like this:

```
function checkEmail(email) {
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var reg1 = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;

    if (reg1.test(email) == false) {
      email.style.border = "1px solid red";
    }else if (reg1.test(email) == true) {
      email.style.border = "1px solid green";
    }
  }
```